# Angular Meteor load order services files

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am looking for a solid solution for the load order of my files of my Angular Meteor project.

I have the current folder structure:

```
[root]
   client
      lib
      modules
        directives
        forms etc..
      startup
      styles
      views
   lib
     collections
   server
     methods
     publisher
```

My angular app is defined in `client/lib/app.js`.
I created a service which would be client only and I put that in `client/lib/services/someService.js'

Now because it is a subfolder it will be loaded first and it will throw an error that angular is not defined. So, then I renamed `app.js' to`00_app.js' and the service to `01_someService.js` to force the order.
This didnt work in my case (probably because I bootstrap the app with `onReady -> angular.bootstrap.document, [ 'appname' ]` )

I fixed it for now by putting the service in `client/modules/services/..'.
However, I rather put it in Lib cause modules is more for re-usable modules and widgets.

Also, when I want to define a service that is used server and client, would put it in `[root]/lib/services..`. This would create the same load issue because Angular is not yet defined. I don't want to use isClient or isServer in the service files.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: How do you load files?

Comment: Meteor loads them for you.See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp